# Loop through all objects in a class at compile time C#

Tags: c#, string, reflection, properties

I need to concat all the properties in my class at compile time to build a string. I have seen similar questions, but they were all dealing with runtime scenarios. Basically, I have a thousand properties, and would rather not list them out by hand again. I know about using reflection to use typeof(X).getProperties(...), but I don't wan't any performance hit for doing this at runtime with reflection. Is there a way for me to loop through all the properties in my class to make a string of all my properties?

```
    Class1 : SomeInterface
    {
            int1;
            int2;
            ...
            int1000;
            string stringOfAllProperties;

            public getAllPropertiesAsString()
            {
               return stringOfAllProperties = int1+int2+int3...;
            }       
     }
```

Comment: Do it manually or use reflection. You could do some AOP style insertion, but that seems like overkill. Is reflection so bad for you? Do you *really* need such high performance that reflection will be even noticeable? Finally, this is a really peculiar thing to do and feels like an XY problem, what are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: "I have a thousand properties, and would rather not" sentence should end there.

Comment: @DavidG right now the performance is a big deal because each of those fields are decoding UDP data and I need to write the string to a file as it comes in. right now I just got it to stop dropping packets, and I'm worried about that being reintroduced. was hoping there is some type of way to list the properties without the reflection performance hit

Comment: You can use reflection to get a list of all the properties. Then you can use [Emit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit?view=netframework-4.7.2) or [Expression Trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/index). That way you only have the perf hit on first run.

Comment: If you don't want a performance hit don't ask for reflection but tell us what you are actually trying to achieve because there is certainly a better approach. For example, why dont you store those integers in a single `List<int>`? Then it was easy: `return String.Concat(intList);`. I don't get what you mean with "loop at compile time" though.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I honestly didn't think of what you suggested (a great idea) and thought reflection was what I was going to be stuck with. I guess when value is initialized, that would be the time to store them in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As others have mentioned, you might have a design problem if you have a thousand properties. Solving that design problem would be my first choice, but if that is not an option...*

Visual Studio supports compile-time (or, to be precise: save-time) code generation via [T4 templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/design-time-code-generation-by-using-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2017), i.e., you can do something like this:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>

class MyClass
{
    <# var properties = new string [] {"int1", "int2", "int3", ...}; #>

    <# foreach (string property in properties) { #>
        private int <#= propertyName #>;
    <# } #>

    public string getAllPropertiesAsString()
    {
        return ""
        <# foreach (string property in properties) { #>
            + <#= propertyName #>;
        <# } #>
    }       
}
```

Note that you will have to install the "Visual Studio extension development" workload during Visual Studio 2017 setup.

Answer (score 1):

I think only reflection will help you here. What you can do is to introduce dictionary where keys will be types and values will be string concatenation results. The dictionary will be used as a singleton in your application. Thereby, you will calculate your string only once per type, hence eliminating performance penalty almost completely.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it done every time you compile and then not during runtime, I would build a method using reflection that never gets called at runtime.  You could then have a second console application whose only purpose it to trigger that method and write the string to a text file or something.  In project properties (of your main project), you can do command line stuff (such as running your console app).

Without knowing what framework you are using, I can't tell you how your console app would interact with the main app.  Your main app could be a dependency of the console app, though, and then your console app could directly use classes in the main app if they are public.

[image]